# How to select a radio button by default?

Tags: html, radio-button

I have some radio buttons and I want one of them to be set as selected by default when the page is loaded. How can I do that?

```
<input type="radio" name="imgsel"  value=""  />
```

Answer (score 1425, accepted):

XHTML solution:

```
<input type="radio" name="imgsel" value="" checked="checked" />
```

Please note, that the actual value of `checked` attribute does not actually matter; it's just a convention to assign `"checked"`. Most importantly, strings like `"true"` or `"false"` don't have any special meaning.

If you don't aim for XHTML conformance, you can simplify the code to:

```
<input type="radio" name="imgsel" value="" checked>
```

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4711036/assign-an-initial-value-to-radio-button-as-checked

Comment: It is just as important to know the gotcha with this:  You need to make sure NO other inputs in this radio button group contain the markup checked="false", nor "checked" by itself.  Otherwise, the last one of these that appears on the page will be checked.  

Only the one you want selected by default should have any markup that contains "checked".

Comment: If the problem persists, you should add the attribute **autocomplete="off"** to force the browser to set the default value.

Comment: "Empty attribute" (still) valid in the current [HTML 5.2 recommendation](https://www.w3.org/TR/2017/REC-html52-20171214/syntax.html#elements-attributes).

Comment: which is better checked="checked" or just checked?

Comment: @OMNIADesignandMarketing `checked="checked"` is better, because, it is accepted in both HTML and XHTML. And it looks better than empty `checked` attribute!

Answer (score 133):

Use the checked attribute.

```
<input type="radio" name="imgsel"  value="" checked />
```

or

```
<input type="radio" name="imgsel"  value="" checked="checked" />
```

Comment: `<input type="radio" name="imgsel"  value="" checked="false" />` also causes the button to be checked.

Comment: I suggest only using `checked` or `checked="checked"` and **vehemently** avoid using "true" as it implies that "false" will do the opposite... which it doesn't.

Comment: The first choice is the right answer. Boolean attributes should not have values.

Comment: @JasonTu Both are correct.  XHTML requires the second version, while HTML allows for either.

Comment: does that mean that checked="checked" is better?

Comment: No, just that it's more backward compatible. But XHTML is sorta dead anyway...

Answer (score 83):

This doesn't exactly answer the question but for anyone using AngularJS trying to achieve this, the answer is slightly different. And actually the normal answer won't work (at least it didn't for me).

Your html will look pretty similar to the normal radio button:

```
<input type='radio' name='group' ng-model='mValue' value='first' />First
<input type='radio' name='group' ng-model='mValue' value='second' /> Second
```

In your controller you'll have declared the `mValue` that is associated with the radio buttons. To have one of these radio buttons preselected, assign the `$scope` variable associated with the group to the desired input's value:

```
$scope.mValue="second"
```

This makes the "second" radio button selected on loading the page.

**EDIT: Since AngularJS 2.x**

The above approach does not work if you're using version 2.x and above. Instead use `ng-checked` attribute as follows:

```
<input type='radio' name='gender' ng-model='genderValue' value='male' ng-checked='genderValue === male'/>Male
<input type='radio' name='gender' ng-model='genderValue' value='female' ng-checked='genderValue === female'/> Female
```

Comment: I was surprised that the accepted answer didn't work - until I read your comment. I too am using AngularJS, and this worked a treat!

Comment: In my case, also using angularjs, I had value but I had to change it to ng-value for it to work properly.

Comment: Ah yes. It should be noted that this is an answer for angular 1.x not greater

Comment: This answer should be deleted because this answer doesn't answer the question.

Comment: Yes I'm using AngularJS and previous answers not worked, I tried your second and it worked.

Answer (score 31):

Add this attribute:

```
checked="checked"
```

Answer (score 20):

They pretty much got it there... just like a checkbox, all you have to do is add the attribute checked="checked" like so:

```
<input type="radio" checked="checked">
```

...and you got it.

Cheers!