# How do I set the value for a radio button group in Php using DOMDocument

Tags: php, dom, radio-button

I've loaded some html using DOMDocument as follows:

```
$dom = new DOMDocument();           
$dom->loadHTML($somehtml);
foreach($dom->getElementsByTagName('*') as $element ){
  if($element->getAttribute("type")=='radio') {
    // I need to set the radio group checked value
  }
}
```

There are 3 radio buttons in each group, all have the same name per group. How can I set a particular radio button's checked property to true? I assume I need to access a collection some how?

Comment: there are documentation here that may be useful: http://www.nusphere.com/kb/phpmanual/function.dom-domelement-setattribute.htm

Answer (score 0):

See the answer here...
[How to select a radio button by default?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5592345/how-to-select-a-radio-button-by-default)

```
<input type="radio" name="imgsel"  value="" checked="checked" />
```

Comment: This is fine for regular static html, I need to set the checked property dynamically in Php using the domDocument.

Answer (score 0):

Here is how I do it.

```
$radio_10 = $html->createElement('input');
$radio_10->setAttribute('onclick', 'ltgGetFire(false);');
$radio_10_attribute = $html->createAttribute('type');
$radio_10_attribute->value = 'radio';
$radio_10->appendChild($radio_10_attribute);
$radio_10_attribute = $html->createAttribute('name');
$radio_10_attribute->value = 'radius';
$radio_10_attribute = $html->createAttribute('checked');

$radio_10->appendChild($radio_10_attribute);
$radio_10_attribute = $html->createAttribute('id');
$radio_10_attribute->value = 'radius_10';
$radio_10->appendChild($radio_10_attribute);
```