# Radio question - Prefill other answer text

Tags: jquery, limesurvey

My institution recently upgared to Limesurvey 3.

I used to prefill a radio question containing an "Other" answer, using this js code :

```
<script>   
$(document).ready(function() {

    $("#question{CODE.qid} input:radio[id$='other']").trigger('click');    

});  </script>
```

I think that code worked with Limesurvey 2 (I am not sure anymore and I cannot test it).

I managed to solve my issue in Limesurvey 3 with this code :

```
<script>   
$(document).ready(function() {

    $("#question{CODE.qid} input:radio:last").trigger('click');    

});  </script>
```

But my question is : In Limesurvey 3, is there a way to prefill answer with the former method, eg using something like `id$='other'`?

EDIT: I need a jquery solution, which is used by Limesurvey.

Additionnaly, I would like to prefill (with an attribute) the text related to the "Other" answer.

Is it possible to do that ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to select a radio button by default?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5592345/how-to-select-a-radio-button-by-default)

Comment: The given answers in your link are not related with jquery, which is used by Limesurvey.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why use jquery/javascript when you can use tool dedicated system …

Add an hidden equation before you question, hide it and put inside

`{CODE=if(is_empty(CODE.NAOK),"-oth-",CODE.NAOK)}
{CODE_other=if(is_empty(CODE.NAOK),TOKEN:ATTRIBUTE_1,CODE_other.NAOK)}`

This fix the 2 feature you need, see https://manual.limesurvey.org/Expression_Manager#Using_Assignment_Operator for reference.

Comment: Thank you Denis. Now I understand EM (after almost 2 years using LM...). on the other hand, the code "-oth-" was not trivial, I could not find it in the documentation.