# Default checked button

Tags: javascript, html, radio-button

Below code is html produced from opencart 2

No radio button is selected when loading page.

How can i have selected the Value="2" as default checked. (javascript or CSS)

```
<div id="payment-custom-field1" class="form-group custom-field" data-sort="0">
<label class="control-label">Invoice</label>
<div id="input-payment-custom-field1">
<div class="radio">
<label>
<input type="radio" value="2" name="custom_field[1]">
Receipt
</label>
</div>
<div class="radio">
<label>
<input type="radio" value="1" name="custom_field[1]">
Invoice
</label>
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

Solution with javascript

```
(function() {
document.getElementsByName("custom_field[1]")[0].checked=true;
})();
```

Comment: Add `checked` attribute to the input

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Assign an initial value to radio button as checked](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4711036/assign-an-initial-value-to-radio-button-as-checked)

Comment: What do you mean you can't do that?

Comment: custom fields was made from admin of opencart 2

Comment: I think the question @KostasKon is really asking is: how, in Opencart 2, can I configure a default checked radio button in a group of buttons.

Comment: oh sorry but my experience is very small

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<input type="radio" id="sample" value="2" name="custom_field[1]">
Receipt
</label>
```

Using javascript:

```
document.getElementById("sample").checked = true;
```

Using html:
   You can simply add `checked` attribute to your html element

Using the element name:

```
(function() {
   document.getElementsByName("custom_field[1]")[0].checked=true;
})();
```

https://jsfiddle.net/pandiyancool/vb73q59w/

Comment: I can't add id to code. Is opencart and custom fields.

Comment: then you can add checked attribute to the html code

Comment: Or  you can use getElementsByName("custom_field[1]").checked=true;

Comment: Opencart is written in php. Custom fields was made from admin area not with code.

Comment: try and let me know

Comment: Its    document.getElementsByName("custom_field[1]")[0].checked=true;
check the updated answer

Comment: welcome! If you feel answer is helpful, please accept and upvote the answer by clicking the tick symbol next to the answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply add `checked` attribute

`<input type="radio" value="2" name="custom_field[1]" checked>`

Comment: The code produced from php (opencart) and i use custom fields. I can't add "checked"

Answer (score 0):

The solution with javascript was the below code:

document.getElementsByName("custom_field[1]")[0].checked=tru‌​e;

Thank you Pandiyan Cool

Comment: You don't have repost the answer! it will create duplicates. You can click the tick symbol next to the original answer itself which helps you