# I want to make the first value of a radio list be checked by default in Open Cart

Tags: php, opencart

I added `checked=checked`, but the last option was selected. I want the first option. How can I do that?

```
<?php


         if ($options) { ?>
          <?php $i=1; foreach ($options as $option) { ?>

            <?php if ($option['type'] == 'select') { ?>
                <?php if($i==2) {    $s=0;?>
                <div id="option-<?php echo $option['product_option_id']; ?>" class="mug_option" style="float:left; width:45%;">
                  <?php echo $text_imprint_side1;?>

                  <?php foreach ($option['option_value'] as $option_value) { ?>

                  <div><input type="radio" checked="checked" name="mug_option[<?php echo $option['product_option_id']; ?>]" value="<?php echo $option_value['product_option_value_id']; ?>" id="mug-option-value-<?php echo $option_value['product_option_value_id']; ?>" class="color_opt" />
  <label for="mug-option-value-<?php echo $option_value['product_option_value_id']; ?>"><?php echo $option_value['name']; ?>
   <?php if ($option_value['price']) { ?>
    <input type="hidden" name="opt_price" id="opt_price<?php echo $option_value['product_option_value_id']; ?>" value="<?php echo $option_value['price_without_symbol']; ?>" />
   <?php } else { ?>
    <input type="hidden" name="opt_price" id="opt_price<?php echo $option_value['product_option_value_id']; ?>" value="0" />
   <?php } ?>

  </label>
  </div>
                 <?php } ?>
                </div>
                <?php } ?>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to select a radio button by default?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5592345/how-to-select-a-radio-button-by-default)

Comment: in `foreach` loop you checking each radio button so you just end up with last one checked

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Assign an initial value to radio button as checked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4711036/assign-an-initial-value-to-radio-button-as-checked)

Answer (score 1):

This is because the `foreach` loop adds the check for all radio options, so the last one will be checked by default. You need to add an `if` condition in the `foreach` loop like this:

```
<?php
$i=1; 
foreach ($option['option_value'] as $option_value) {
    ?><div><input type="radio" <?php if($i==1) {echo "checked='checked'"; $i++;
} ?> ......blah blah blah
```

Comment: Edited... `$i++` should be add under `if` statement