# Select first radio button by default

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, radio-button

I'm trying to select the first radio button by default. However, every code I have tried has not worked. Any help would be appreciated.

jsfiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/te2b5dqy/

```js
$('.radiogroup').change(function(e) {
  const $this = $(this), $link = $("#url");
  $link.html($this.val());
  $link.attr("href", $this.attr("data-url"));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="radio" name="radiogroup" id="radiogroup1" class="radiogroup" value="Google" data-url="https://google.com" />
<input type="radio" name="radiogroup" id="radiogroup2" class="radiogroup" value="Bing" data-url="https://www.bing.com/" />

<a id="url" href="" target="_blank">null</a>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Assign an initial value to radio button as checked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4711036/assign-an-initial-value-to-radio-button-as-checked)

Comment: Why not just set it using html ?? http://jsfiddle.net/te2b5dqy/2/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simply add `.eq(0).click()`

```js
$('.radiogroup').change(function(e) {
  const $this = $(this), $link = $("#url");
  $link.html($this.val());
  $link.attr("href", $this.attr("data-url"));
}).eq(0).click(); //<<<<<<< here
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="radio" name="radiogroup" id="radiogroup1" class="radiogroup" value="Google" data-url="https://google.com" />
<input type="radio" name="radiogroup" id="radiogroup2" class="radiogroup" value="Bing" data-url="https://www.bing.com/" />

<a id="url" href="" target="_blank">null</a>
```

**OR**  `.eq(0).prop('checked' , true).change()`

```js
$('.radiogroup').change(function(e) {
  const $this = $(this), $link = $("#url");
  $link.html($this.val());
  $link.attr("href", $this.attr("data-url"));
}).eq(0).prop("checked" , true).change(); //<<<<<<< here
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="radio" name="radiogroup" id="radiogroup1" class="radiogroup" value="Google" data-url="https://google.com" />
<input type="radio" name="radiogroup" id="radiogroup2" class="radiogroup" value="Bing" data-url="https://www.bing.com/" />

<a id="url" href="" target="_blank">null</a>
```

**Additional:** A lot of ways to select the first radio `.eq(0)` , `.first()` , `.filter(':eq(0)')` , `.filter(':nth-child(1)')`

Answer (score 1):

The checked="checked" will do the trick

```
<input type="radio" name="radiogroup" id="radiogroup1" checked="checked" 
 class="radiogroup" value="Google" data-url="https://google.com" />
```

Answer (score 1):

## Solution

**checked** attribute will solve this

## Here is the code snippet

```html
<input type="radio" checked />
<input type="radio" />
```

Answer (score 0):

XHTML solution:

```
<input type="radio" name="radiogroup" id="radiogroup1" class="radiogroup" 
value="Google"  checked="checked" data-url="https://google.com" />
```

Note, the actual value of checked attribute does not matter actually; it's just a way to assign "checked". Importantly, like "true" or "false" don't have any special meaning.

If you don't aim for XHTML, you can make the code more simplify:

```
<input type="radio" name="radiogroup" id="radiogroup1" class="radiogroup" 
value="Google" data-url="https://google.com" checked>
```