# some websites want to auto select input radio in my chrome

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome

In my work,I have to face some situations that I have to select some specific input radio, like familiar or strangers, I usually select strangers. If there any ideas to auto select [`strangers`] ?

I press *F12* to use console to active these code:

> ```
> document.getElementsByClassName('ant-radio-input')[1].checked = true
> ```

but the html displays not selected.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4711036/assign-an-initial-value-to-radio-button-as-checked

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Assign an initial value to radio button as checked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4711036/assign-an-initial-value-to-radio-button-as-checked)

Comment: use checked = "checked" for the value you want to be checked initially

Comment: What do you want to achieve? Is this your code you are trying to change, or are you using other sites' service and want to automate the filling out of forms?

Answer (score 0):

There are some Chrome plugins you can use for automating tasks like these and make your life easier.

- [Tampermonkey](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/tampermonkey/dhdgffkkebhmkfjojejmpbldmpobfkfo)
- [ScriptAutoRunner](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/scriptautorunner/gpgjofmpmjjopcogjgdldidobhmjmdbm)

So essentially, save your script in one of these plugins and whenever you open that website again it will be pre-selected.

Answer (score 0):

Just use this in your input code: **input type="radio" name="strangers" value="" checked="checked"**

Answer (score 0):

You could add a bookmark in your browser with the JS code. This should be prefixed with `javascript:`

So add this URL to your bookmarks

`javascript:document.getElementsByClassName('ant-radio-input')[1].checked = true:`